# Gson deserialize to List<Object> where generic type of list is given as classname

Tags: java, reflection, gson

I need a function of the following form

```
List<Object> deserialize(String className, String jsonString){
}
```

Here the jsonString can be something like the following and the className will be some thing like `com.example.mycontact`

`[{"name":"myName","mobile":"12344557899"},{"name":"myName","mobile":"12344557899"}]`

Now how do I use gson to convert it to list of Contact. Note that it need not be contact in a different call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a solution.

```
List<Object> deserialize(String className, String jsonString){  
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonArray jsonArray = (JsonArray) parser.parse(jsonString);
    Iterator<JsonElement> iterator = jsonArray.iterator();
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        list.add(gson.fromJson(iterator.next(), className));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Please answer if you have a more elegant solution.